# Unable to connect Android App to local MSSQL database

Tags: android, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012-express

Hi I created a SQL management Database, I wish to connect to the Database through Android App

I am not what I did wrong, I am not able to login.

This my SQL management Studio 2012, My DataBase name I call it DB.
[image: This is my Database Screenshot]

This is my **SQL Server Configuration manager**, what I did is I enable TCP/IP and shared memory.
[image]

And then I enable all the IP, and I set the ALL port to 1433, the dynamic port I leave it empty.
[image: double click on TCP/IP]

[image]

I create the database using this username
[image]

This is what my code is like for my Android Java file, connection to database

```
     String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";


     String connString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433/db;encrypt=false;
user=username;password=1234;instance=SQLEXPRESS;";
        String username = "username";
        String password = "1234";
        int id;
```

Is it something wrong with my step, how come it is not connecting?

Comment: So what is the error could be?

Answer (score 0):

Connecting directly to a DB from android is highly discouraging. The primary reason is performance. See, it is really expensive to keep a remote connection alive than rather just call Web Services on demand which is more portable and also more secure.

Therefore, its better to develop a REST API instead for your service and invoke it from client android app or any other client for that matter.

Edit: For your current issue at hand, see if it works by replacing localhost IP to the real(assuming 192.168.0.16 is also ipa4 ip?) one.

```
String connString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.0.16/db;encrypt=false;
user=username;password=1234;instance=SQLEXPRESS;";
```

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: failed to connect to /192.168.0.16 (port 1433): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out) I experience connection timeout. what could be the error?